# Rasterio merge results is 1 pixel wider than input rasters

Tags: python, merge, rasterio

I'm trying to overlay one georeferenced map onto another georeferenced map (and then apply a mask).
I can use rasterio's merge function to do this, but the result is one pixel wider than the first data source even though I used the bounds from the first data source.

```
print(areaData.shape)  ##==> (769, 1024)
mergedImage,_ = merge([areaData,overlayMapData], bounds=areaData.bounds, method='last')
print(mergedImage.shape)  ##==> (3, 770, 1024)
```

I thought this might be caused by a rounding issue in the coordinates, or maybe the resolution parameter has to be set get the merge result to actually be the same size as the first input image.  But I don't know how to resolve those, or whether it's something else completely.

I've confirmed that there is an extra column of pixels on the right of the image.  If I cut the right 1 pixel, then the image is exactly the same.

```
mergedImage,_ = merge([areaData,areaData], bounds=areaData.bounds, method='last')
overlayMap = np.dstack([mergedImage[0], mergedImage[1], mergedImage[2]])
w,h,c = overlayMap.shape
removeRight = overlayMap[0:w-1, 0:h]
print(np.sum(removeRight-areaMask)) ##==> 0
```

Here areaMask is the image of the areaData.

The arrays need to be the same size so I can apply the mask, which is a raster already in the same shape as the areaData file.  If `merge` always added a column of pixels on the right, then I could correct it with this kludge, but clearly it shouldn't be doing this, and **it's not consistent**.  Also, I want to understand why the actual output differs from what I expect from the documentation.

Comment: so, any success?

Comment: nope, I just had to check for it and fix them manually.

Comment: thanks for that extra info. i have a similar issue. i am not sure where i can find the proper documentation explaining how merging is happening that could lead in changes in size